# Temporary fix for bad contactor?

Tags: hvac, compressor

After doing some replacement for the ac, the contactor stopped working. It won't close when I turn the ac on. when I pushed it in, the compressor was able to start.
[image]

I can't go out to find a new one until next week, and it's relly hot this weekend.

So, can I temporarily glue it closed? 
And does change the contactor is enough?

Sincerely,
Alt

Comment: From the photo I assume this is a rooftop package unit with a gas furnace, and that is a pretty old electronic spark ignition module shown right of the contactor.  If this is the same unit you wrote about on August 22nd, then you may be wasting your time.  In my estimation that unit is not getting fixed without some professional level a/c skills.  If the unit is very old then most pros will suggest complete replacement.  You might find an ace that will help you out, but that is hard to come by.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Yys, it's the one. I did have have someone come out to fix it some years ago ( about $1000). I think I will do all I can this time since it does not cost much for everything I have done. I changed the capacitor, cleaned the coils, and was going to change the fan but the wires was so different from the new one; I left it there since its working now. Then, I called people from cityultilities. They checked and said the fuse(s) blown. I changed all the fuses. Now, the contactor died, and it's cheap, I want to give it a shot :)

Comment: I understand your motivation.  Please be careful. Gluing a contactor shut, if you succeeded, would be a very serious mistake.  If you know for a fact that the contactor coil has failed (i.e. there is voltage supplied to the coil but the coil does not energize), then replacing that with a compatible model could be an easy fix.  On the other hand, if there is no voltage to the coil then the contactor could be locked out for safety reasons.

Comment: Since you mention someone else serviced the unit some years ago, perhaps that person serviced it improperly.  In an old R22 package unit with a fixed orifice metering device, overcharging the unit could cause (1) high head pressure tripping the cut out in hot weather and (2) liquid flood back to the compressor with ice formation on the crankcase.  Your unit may be overcharged.  Charging these units properly requires knowledge and finesse, or the charge should be weighed in.  I am sorry to say that many techs do this incorrectly.

Comment: Understand. I will see if changing the conntactor help, or I'm done with it. Anyway, the weather is going to be cooler, I'm fine with 80 degree. Thanks

Comment: 'when I pushed it in, the compressor was able to start' - are you sure you didn't make this bit up?

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THAT,  unless of course you don't mind setting your unit or house on fire. The contractor is not engaging for a reason and you need to find out what that reason is. Do some trouble-shooting first.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily mean that the contactor is bad.  When you set your thermostat in the house to call for cooling, do you have voltage at the coil of the contactor?  It looks like that should be the two small wires at the top colored red and white.  Check the voltage there, and if you have proper voltage while calling for cooling, then it likely is a bad contactor.  However, you might find that there is no voltage when calling for cooling.  This would indicate a control power issue.  You will need to troubleshoot the reason why you don't have any voltage there when you should.

Comment: I check the votage at the thermostat (the red and white wires), I have 25.1 v . It should be fine, correct? It starts getting hot now :)

Comment: You said that you checked the voltage "at the thermostat".  Did you check the wires right at the contactor itself?  If you have that voltage at the contactor,  it is likely that the contactor is bad since you are able to push the contactor in manually and it will start the unit.  If there is voltage at the contactor (red and white wires) and you push the contactor in, does it stay in, or does it come right back out?  Sometimes, the coils get weak and can't pull the contactor in, but can hold it in.

Comment: I only checked at the thermostat, not at the contactor- if that's what you're asking. And it came right back when I released it. Should that be fine for about 3 days?

Comment: just read your first answer again, I wont be able to get to the contactor until tonight, I will give some update later.

Comment: The only reason I suggested checking at the contactor is to make sure voltage was actually being applied to the coil of the contactor. I assume the thermostat is in the house a distance away. If the wire is broken, you could see voltage at the thermostat but not at the coil.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the exact same thing. And found that one of the legs in the disconnect box or my Breakers or fuses depending on how old your unit is I found that one of the legs when we put the breaker in was corroded and bent and the legs were vibrating when the unit came on there for causing power to Surge and when that happens the unit is not getting the voltage necessary causing the contactor to trip after replacing the disconnect box and installing new Breakers problem stopped

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's impossible to understand what you mean; please take a moment to add a few periods, and some more explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Contactors don't quite work that way they are a relay, a controll voltage at a small amperage pulls the contacts in to connect a large load. A circuit breaker can trip but a contactor is on or off there is no trip.